# return list of objects in s3 prefix using boto3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the boto3 code below.  In the code I am trying to get a list of objects in an s3 prefix.  The complete path to the object in the s3 prefix is :

path to file:

```
s3://our_data/our_folder/part-00000-bf597559-8a11-4e6b-8631-ef7c138b4583-c000.txt
```

When I run the code below it doesn't return anything, but I could swear a couple months ago it worked.  Did anything change with boto3 related to this recently, or am I missing something in my code?

code:

```
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3',
                         region_name='us-west-2')


trz_bucket = 'our_data'


trz_prefix = 'our_folder/'


result = s3_client.list_objects(Bucket=trz_bucket, Prefix=trz_prefix, Delimiter='v')

result.get('CommonPrefixes')
```

Comment: What does `result` contain after calling `list_objects`? My recollection is that `CommonPrefixes` is only returned if there is a `Delimiter` specified in the call.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thank you for pointing that out.  I forgot to add the delimiter.  I updated my original post.  Nothing is returned when I run result.get('CommonPrefixes').  Adding or leaving the Delimiter='v' returns no results in either case.

Comment: Why `Delimiter` is `v`?

Answer (score 0):

The `CommonPrefixes` will be returned if you provide a `Delimiter`:

```
list_objects(Bucket=trz_bucket, Prefix=trz_prefix, Delimiter='/')
```

Here' an example of using `Delimiter` and `CommonPrefixes` using the AWS CLI (which would work the same as using boto3):

```
$ aws s3 mb s3://test-delimiter
make_bucket: test-delimiter

$ aws s3 cp x.py s3://test-delimiter/folder1/
upload: ./x.py to s3://test-delimiter/folder1/x.py                

$ aws s3 cp x.py s3://test-delimiter/folder2/
upload: ./x.py to s3://test-delimiter/folder2/x.py                

$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-delimiter --delimiter '/'
{
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "folder1/"
        },
        {
            "Prefix": "folder2/"
        }
    ]
}

$ aws s3 cp x.py s3://test-delimiter/folder1/folder3/
upload: ./x.py to s3://test-delimiter/folder1/folder3/x.py        

$ aws s3api list-objects --bucket test-delimiter --delimiter '/' --prefix folder1/
{
    "Contents": [
        {
            "Key": "folder1/x.py",
            "LastModified": "2021-06-05T07:52:35+00:00",
            "ETag": "\"1083f8ddcea96dd6b9d8a3a582373c71\"",
            "Size": 727,
            "StorageClass": "STANDARD"
            }
        }
    ],
    "CommonPrefixes": [
        {
            "Prefix": "folder1/folder3/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tried list_objects(Bucket=trz_bucket, Prefix=trz_prefix, Delimiter='/') it still doesn't return anything.  If I change trz_prefix = 'our_folder/' to trz_prefix = 'our_folder' it will return 'our_folder'.

Comment: I tried a different prefix, and it returned the object in that prefix with Delimiter='v'.  Delimiter='/' still didn't return anything in that case.  So must be some issue with the prefix I provided in the original post.  thanks for your help.

Comment: the only difference I can find between the prefix that worked and the original one I posted is the one that worked contained a csv and the one that I originally posted contains a '.txt' file, would that prevent list_objects from being able to return the path to the object?

Comment: The delimiter should be a slash (`/`). I have added an example, above.